# Can't get Window.Open to work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a form that opens to a specific website when right username and password are given. The problem is that the window.open won't work correctly, when it goes to load, the address is:

> https://www.weltec.ac.nzfile///home/wilmint/User%20name%20pswd%20test

When I need it to end at '.nz' Here is my code:

```js
var URL = "https://www.weltec.ac.nz" + location.href;

function check(form) {
  if (form.userid.value == "Weltec" && form.pswrd.value == "2015") {
    window.open(URL)
  } else {
    alert("Error Password or Username")
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="login">
    Enter User Name:
    <input type="text" name="userid"><br> Enter Password:
    <input type="password" name="pswrd"><br>
    <input type="button" onClick="check (this.form)" value="Login">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone see what's wrong? I'm still a beginner with Javascript and HTML so any help I can get would be really appreciated.

Comment: Which URL should be opened in the new window?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing the `+ location.href` , it will add the the current url to the new one.

In other words you you are currently on `https://www.weltec.ac.nz/login.html` then the window.open will take you to `https://www.weltec.ac.nzhttps://www.weltec.ac.nz/login.html`

Just use `var URL = "https://www.weltec.ac.nz"`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using wrong javascript location property. When you are using href it used to

> Return the entire URL (of the current page)

Instead of that you are suppose to use pathname which will return

> Return the path name of the current URL

Change this code `var URL = "https://www.weltec.ac.nz" + location.href;` to this `var URL = "https://www.weltec.ac.nz" + location.pathname;`